# PySide6 read file path include chinese failed in Qfilesystemmodel

Tags: python, encoding, decoding, python-3.10, pyside6

I define a filesystem manager with PySide6,and the main code is:

```
    self.model = FileSystemModelImpl()
    self.root_parent = self.model.setRootPath(img_dir)
  
    self.sort_proxy_model =MySortFilterProxyModel()
    self.sort_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
    source_index = self.model.index(img_dir)
    proxy_index = self.sort_proxy_model.mapFromSource(source_index)

    self.tree_view = QTreeViewImpl()
    self.tree_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.tree_view.setModel(self.sort_proxy_model)
    self.tree_view.setRootIndex(proxy_index)
    self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.tree_response)
```

when I select a file, it will call the tree_response function, part of which

```
    def tree_response(self, selected: QtCore.QItemSelection, deselected: QtCore.QItemSelection):
        self.file_path = self.get_current_path()
```

which include the get_current_path() function:

```
def get_current_path(self):
    index = self.tree_view.currentIndex()
    #file_path = self.model.filePath(self.sort_proxy_model.mapToSource(index))
    file_path = self.model.fileInfo(self.sort_proxy_model.mapToSource(index)).absoluteFilePath()

    return file_path
```

The file_path include chinese. When I run this code in Mac, everything goes OK. I can use the file_path to do some postprocess like reading image by opencv.
However, when I run it in Window, it failed. The file_path was wrong like:

```
 C:/panda_eye/panda_eye_val/img/Θ╗æΣ║║@160-Θ╗æ-σÑ│-2248_left_crop.jpg
```

I use python 3.10 both in python 3.10. And i use sys.getfilesystemencoding to get the system encoding type and they are both utf-8.

=====================update questions==============================

Here are the minimal example
in main.py, the code is :

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.')))

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication)
from simple_imageviewer import ImageViewer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

import multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    arg_parser = ArgumentParser(description="Image Viewer",
                                formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    arg_parser.add_argument('file', type=str, nargs='?', help='Image file')
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    image_viewer = ImageViewer()

    if args.file and not image_viewer.load_file(args.file):
        sys.exit(-1)

    image_viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and the simple_imageviewer.py is

```
# Copyright (C) 2022 The Qt Company Ltd.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-Qt-Commercial OR BSD-3-Clause
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QFileSystemModel, QTableView, QWidget)
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
import PySide6.QtCore as QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import  Slot, QSortFilterProxyModel

import os
import cv2



img_dir = "C:\\Users\\Moon\\OneDrive\\文档\\工作\\code\\python\\test\\"
    
class ImageViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # 自适应屏幕大小
        primary_size = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableSize()
        screen_height = primary_size.height()
        screen_width = primary_size.width()
        self.move(screen_width * 0.1, screen_height * 0.1)

        self.tree_view_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
    
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.root_parent = self.model.setRootPath(img_dir)
      
        self.sort_proxy_model =QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.sort_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        source_index = self.model.index(img_dir)
        proxy_index = self.sort_proxy_model.mapFromSource(source_index)


        self.tree_view = QTableView()
        header = self.tree_view.verticalHeader()
        header.setSectionHidden(0, True)

        self.tree_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.sort_proxy_model)
        self.tree_view.setRootIndex(proxy_index)
        
        #self.tree_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(img_dir))
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.tree_response)
        self.tree_view_layout.addWidget(self.tree_view, 0, 0)
        self.grid_layout.addLayout(self.tree_view_layout, 0, 0, 0, 1)
      
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)


    def get_current_path(self):
        index = self.tree_view.currentIndex()
        source_index = self.sort_proxy_model.mapToSource(index)
        file_info = QtCore.QFileInfo(self.model.filePath(source_index))
        file_path = file_info.absoluteFilePath()
        return file_path

        
    @Slot()
    def tree_response(self, selected: QtCore.QItemSelection, deselected: QtCore.QItemSelection):
        file_path = self.get_current_path()
        img = cv2.imread(file_path)
        print(img.shape)
        print(file_path)
```

and the file struct of "C:\Users\Moon\OneDrive\文档\工作\code\python\test\" is

```
    moon@bogon test % tree
.
└── 你好.png

1 directory, 1 file
```

when i run the main.py in window, there is a file manager gui
[image]

there comes to a error:

```
C:\Users\Moon\OneDrive\文档\工作\code\python>python3.10 main.py
[ WARN:0@2.063] global loadsave.cpp:244 cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/Users/Moon/OneDrive/µûçµíú/σ╖ÑΣ╜£/code/python/test/Σ╜áσÑ╜.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moon\OneDrive\文档\工作\code\python\simple_imageviewer.py", line 67, in tree_response
    print(img.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

howerver, I can normally read the image in mac system. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share expected *`file_path`* along with provided garbled one.

Comment: As @JosefZ said we need a minimal reproducible  example. It seems you have a problem with the encoding. Maybe you can try with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'zh_CN.UTF-8')` at the beginning fo your code. This will set the system regional settings to 'Simplified Chinese' and use the `UTF-8` encoding to handle Chinese characters.

Comment: I have posted the  minimal reproducible example. Could you please take a look for me? @JosefZ

Comment: regretfully, it didn't work @WhoKnowsMe

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:  `print( '你好.png'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp437'))` returns `Σ╜áσÑ╜.png` and `print( img_dir.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp437'))` -> ```C:\Users\Moon\OneDrive\µûçµíú\σ╖ÑΣ╜£\code\python\test\```…

Comment: I turn img = cv2.imread(file_path) to         
img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(fileName, dtype=np.uint8), -1) and it works!!